# How to see if the nyquist plot is stable or unstable?

Tags: matlab, nyquist

Is there a method to determine the stability of the nyquist plot to check if it's stable or unstable ? I currently needs to manually input the transfer function to another m.file to view the pz location to determine

```
syms s w

    G = (2*s+1)/((s^2)+(5*s)+6); %transfer function
    G_w = subs(G,s,j*w);
    W= [-100:0.1:100]; %[min_range:step size:max_range]
    nyq = eval(subs(G_w,w,W));

    x = real(nyq)
    y = imag(nyq)

    plot(x,y)
```

This is the code i am using

Comment: Does using * B = isstable(nyq) * , in this case work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this video quite useful!
[Nyquist Stability Criterion, Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sof3meN96MA) 
All this channel video are really good for control theory and give a better understanding to then move everything on MATLAB.

Hope this was useful.

Comment: Anything will help me alot ! Thank you for your reply !